# Why is my Vuex getter returning TRUE on the client side and FALSE on the server side?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm using NUXT middleware to check if a user is logged in or not, and protect certain routes accordingly.  The problem is, when a logged-in user refreshes the page on one of the protected routes, the session is lost.

I have a getter in my Vuex store state (using NUXT):

```
getters: {
  isLoggedIn (state) {
    return !isEmpty(state.auth.email) && !isEmpty(state.auth.token)
  }
}
```

I'm accessing this getter in middleware to redirect unauthenticated users to a login page:

```
let isLoggedIn = context.store.getters.isLoggedIn
if (!isLoggedIn && protectedRoutes.includes(context.route.name)) {
    let language = context.store.language ? context.store.language : 'en'
    context.redirect(`/${language}/login`)
  }
```

But it's not working. When I console.log() the value of this getter, I get TRUE on the client side and FALSE on the server side. How can I keep them both in sync with Vue/Vuex?

Furthermore, whenever I console.log() the context object on the server side, it appears to be in its initial state. There must be something fundamentally wrong with my approach.

Comment: how do you pass the `state` parameter to `isLoggedIn` ?

Comment: It's just a getter on the Vuex store, so it's consuming the current store state instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When user refresh a page all vuex state is lost and start from new. You need to initialize user somewhere like [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action)

```
actions: {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    if (req.session.user) {
      commit('user', req.session.user)
    }
  }
}
```